# Scrabble Game For ubuntu?

Tags: games

I have a friend who is running ubuntu.  He has a scrabble computer game that he wants to install.  He got it out of a cereal box, but he likes it and wants to play it anyways.

Where could he look for the game?

Answer (score 6):

Since the game will be only for Windows (probably) , you will need to install it through **wine**.

But there is also a scrabble game natively for Ubuntu, called **PyScrabble**. You can install it via executing `sudo apt-get install pyscrabble` in the terminal or search for "PyScrabble" in the Software Center and install it.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find a Scrabble game for Ubuntu that I liked but "Networdz" for Windows works fine under Wine and I have been playing that flawlessly on various Ubuntu versions for years.

Answer (score 1):

download

https://github.com/apikler/ScrabbleAI

it is a python app run with

```
perl ~/wherever/ScrabbleAI-master/scrabbleai.pl
```

might also need

```
sudo apt install  libgtk2-perl
sudo apt install  libcanberra-gtk-module
sudo apt install  libgnome2-canvas-perl
```

there was a big issue as it wanted dependency

libgnome2-canvas-perl which could not be found

which I could get by putting in  shutter in the repository

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linuxuprising/shutter

sudo apt install  libgnome2-canvas-perl
```

(no need to actually install shutter though)

only usability issue is inability to pick you own tiles (I suspect it cheats  but source code is available). no undo or save games , alas

I also found it convenient to put its dictionary as text the file !/.../ScrabbleAI-master/Backend/enable  into my web browser for viewing and definition lookups, which would be a nice new feature for the game to do.

Comment: works with 20.04 and worked with 19.10

Comment: but for 22.04.1  Unable to locate package libgnome2-canvas-perl and I spent hours on it to no avail. another one was for java, which does not work for me.

Comment: the error is Can't locate Gtk2.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Gtk2 module) (@INC contains: /home/pedro/Downloads/ScrabbleAI-master/lib /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.34.0 /usr/local/share/perl/5.34.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.34 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.34 /usr/share/perl/5.34 /usr/local/lib/site_perl) at /home/pedro/Downloads/ScrabbleAI-master/scrabbleai.pl line 28.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /home/xxxxxx/Downloads/ScrabbleAI-master/scrabbleai.pl line 28

Comment: not working on a clean install of 22.04 Jammy. apparentely every now and again we have to throw out our old apps and forget abuot them because they are not supported. we can play vintage dos games in a DOS box but for old Linux games, you are on your own. end rant

Answer (score 0):

finally found one that worked, Ubuntu 22.04

https://sourceforge.net/projects/gscrabble/

```
git clone https://sourceforge.net/projects/gscrabble/
bash install
```

then goto menu (top right) preferences, Language, choose English (it is written in hindu or somesuch). add a dictionary, just a text file with words and one word per line.
there was an issue with the open this text file up, that dialogue stayed up, so I had to close the program , which it did gracefully close,
and run in terminal again

```
gscrabble
```

then choosing player said language file not properly done, so it did proceed, no need to rechoose the file.

sound can be disabled.

Comment: love the way with touchscreen touch letter then touch the board, no need to drag. hotkeys ) for accept word, C for change letters etc

Comment: the worst thing about it is it only shows each players total score and does not show how much the last move, or previous moves, made. tempted to modify it myself and improve it. overall a pleasant first experience.  It's name is Golden Scrabble.